# Java8 Lambda for conditional reduce operation

Tags: java, java-8

I have a collection of TimeSlots and I want to transform it to another collection of TimeSlots by merging connected TimeSlots.
here is the working copy of code -

```
    private List<TimeSlot> getMergedConnectedSlots(final List<TimeSlot> orderedSlot) {
        List<TimeSlot> mergedOrdered = new ArrayList<>();
        mergedOrdered.add(orderedSlot.get(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < orderedSlot.size() - 1; i ++ ) {
            TimeSlot ts1 = mergedOrdered.get(mergedOrdered.size() - 1);
            TimeSlot ts2 = orderedSlot.get(i + 1);
            Range<Long> ts1Range = Range.closed(ts1.getStartTime(), ts1.getEndTime());
            Range<Long> ts2Range = Range.closed(ts2.getStartTime(), ts2.getEndTime());
            if(ts1Range.isConnected(ts2Range)) {
                val mergedRange = ts1Range.span(ts2Range);
                mergedOrdered.remove(mergedOrdered.size() - 1);
                mergedOrdered.add(new TimeSlot(mergedRange.lowerEndpoint(), mergedRange.upperEndpoint()));
            } else {
                mergedOrdered.add(ts2);
            }
        }
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(mergedOrdered);
    }
```

As it is evident that above code is verbose and lot of lines. I am wondering if there is a concise lamda/functional way of improving this code? 
I tried using reduce operation but that was not working for me as it ends up reducing it to single TimeSlot.

Comment: is this Java or Scala? `val` is scala keyword

Comment: `val` could be from `Lombok`

Comment: Looks like *concise* is unlikely - see [Java 8 Stream mixing two elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771415/java-8-stream-mixing-two-elements) for some possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could make your code more optimal not using additional object for merging. E.g. using POJO. I did not test this code in many cases, but this is my approach:

```
public class Foo {
    private static final Comparator<TimeSlot> TIME_SLOT_COMPARATOR = (slot1, slot2) -> {
        int res = Long.compare(slot1.startTime, slot2.startTime);
        return res != 0 ? res : Long.compare(slot1.endTime, slot2.endTime);
    };

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Set<TimeSlot> slots = new TreeSet<>(TIME_SLOT_COMPARATOR);

        slots.add(new TimeSlot(1, 3));
        slots.add(new TimeSlot(2, 6));
        slots.add(new TimeSlot(4, 5));
        slots.add(new TimeSlot(7, 8));

        Set<TimeSlot> res = getMergedConnectedSlots(slots);
        // res[0]: [1:6]
        // res[1]: [7:8]
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class TimeSlot {
        private long startTime;
        private long endTime;
    }

    private static Set<TimeSlot> getMergedConnectedSlots(TreeSet<TimeSlot> slots) {
        Set<TimeSlot> res = new TreeSet<>(TIME_SLOT_COMPARATOR);

        long startTime = -1;
        long endTime = -1;

        for (TimeSlot slot : slots) {
            if (startTime == -1) {
                startTime = slot.startTime;
                endTime = slot.endTime;
            } else if (slot.startTime > endTime) {
                res.add(new TimeSlot(startTime, endTime));
                startTime = slot.startTime;
                endTime = slot.endTime;
            } else
                endTime = Math.max(endTime, slot.endTime);
        }

        if (startTime != -1)
            res.add(new TimeSlot(startTime, endTime));

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can afford using additional object as the list wouldn't be very long and scope is limited to stack. I looking for more functional and concise code something similar to map.reduce paradigm.

Comment: According to me, that simple things should be done simply. Personally, I do not have objective to use streams in any case.